# Kubectl update/upgrade and view version is not matching

Tags: kubernetes

I dit a new install of kubectl and after i get the message:

> Warnings:
>    - kubernetes-cli - kubernetes-cli v1.13.3 already installed.  Use --force to reinstall, specify a version to install, or try upgrade.

But when I ask *kubectl version*
I get this information:

> C:\Users\myname> kubectl version
>
> Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.11",
>   GitCommit:"637c7e288581ee40ab4ca210618a89a555b6e7e9",
>   GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:38:32Z",
>   GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"} Server
>   Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.5",
>   GitCommit:"753b2dbc622f5cc417845f0ff8a77f539a4213ea",
>   GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:31:35Z",
>   GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

**Why I don't find the version number 1.13 in the version information's?**

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had this issue because I have both Docker *and* the Kubernetes CLI installed; at time of writing, Docker currently ships with version v1.10 of kubectl, whereas the Kubernetes CLI ships with v1.14

The simple solution was just to re-order my environment variables so that the Docker version of kubectl was *after* the Kubernetes CLI version

Answer (score 1):

Please check which executable file is refered to *kubectl* command using:

`C:\where kubectl`

This should be the same as you are trying to install.

There are few methods for installing kubectl listed in [installation guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/). For example by [using powershell](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-with-powershell-from-psgallery) you could accidentally install kubectl in your temp directory if you do not specify a `DownloadLocation`.

Answer (score -1):

use the below command to check kubectl client version

```
kubectl version --short --client=true
```

if you want to check both kubectl client and api server version, then try the below command

```
kubectl version --short
```

```
master $ kubectl version --short --client=true
Client Version: v1.11.3
master $ kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.11.3
Server Version: v1.11.3
```

Comment: what i get out is:
Client Version: v1.10.11
what is corresponding in the initial posting.

But why I don't have the newest version of 13.3 when I just installed kubectl new and I got the message "kubernetes-cli v1.13.3 already installed"???

Comment: i see that you are running the commands on windows. i use linux. what i can think of is that you might need to update the binary path in system PATH variable.

Comment: You should run a which command, to begin with, and also check the loading pattern defined in your PATH environment variable.